# Excel - Combine Multiple Columns into One if Data Exists

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have multiple lists that are in separate columns in excel however some columns do not include data. What I need to do is combine these columns that do have data into one big column.

```
Row 1 | A B
Row 2 | C D E
Row 3 | F 
Row 4 | G H I
```

Should combine into:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H 
I
```

With no blank rows in between. Would rather not use macros if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: very easy in VBA, very difficult if ever feasible without. I suggest you go on with VBA and we will be pleased to help you take it to a good end.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want a macro? A formula will be pretty tricky (well, maybe not considering the cleverness of some users here), but certainly VBA will be a much quicker solution.  Also, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a couple ways to do this.  Use the formula below.

=INDEX(MyData,1+INT((ROW(A1)-1)/COLUMNS(MyData)),MOD(ROW(A1)-1+COLUMNS(MyData),COLUMNS(MyData))+1)

This assumes 'MyData' is a named range.

As an alternative, you could use a simple VBA script to do the job.

```
Sub ConvertRangeToColumn()
Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range, Rng As Range
Dim rowIndex As Integer
xTitleId = "Title"
Set Range1 = Application.Selection
Set Range1 = Application.InputBox("Source Ranges:", xTitleId, Range1.Address, Type:=8)
Set Range2 = Application.InputBox("Convert to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
rowIndex = 0
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Rng In Range1.Rows
    Rng.Copy
    Range2.Offset(rowIndex, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Transpose:=True
    rowIndex = rowIndex + Rng.Columns.Count
Next
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: updated "Paste:=xlPasteAll" to "Paste:=xlPasteValues" in the macro because there were formulas in the cells and I wanted values but both the regular formula and the macro worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Macros, you will at least need to use filter to avoid the blank rows (zeros rows in my solution).

I have assumed your data lies in columns A, B and C

In column D us the below formulae

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()+2,3)=0,INDEX(A:A,QUOTIENT(ROW()+2,3)),IF(MOD(ROW()+2,3)=1,INDEX(B:B,QUOTIENT(ROW()+2,3)),IF(MOD(ROW()+2,3)=2,INDEX(C:C,QUOTIENT(ROW()+2,3)),"")))
```

Drag the formula down as far as you can. the filter this column to remove zeros.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use VBA macros I think that the best way to get it is to copy column B, the column C, then column D, ... one under each other, like this:

```
A
C
F
G
B
D

H

E

I
```

Then use the menu Data => Remove Duplicates to remove multiple spaces.

If you change idea about using macros just search "unpivot data Excel" on Google and you'll find a plenty of solutions about it.